# Ubuntu 22.04 inserting external USB hard drive disables only the wireless keyboard but not the mouse

Tags: usb, keyboard, 22.04, hard-drive, mouse

I have an old laptop and I am running Ubuntu 22.04 on it and the computer has 3 USB ports (probably USB 2.0). I am using one for wireless adaptor (the internal one does not work), one for the wireless keyboard and mouse. I want to use the third one for an external HDD and when I insert it to the USB, I can't use the keyboard (it sometimes works for the first couple of seconds but then it is gone) but I am able to use the mouse.

I have checked the the TLP config and the file does not contain any information which is weird as well. I guess there is no TLP running so no battery saving options whatsoever.

Also I checked the autosuspend settings and it is set to -1 so it should not be that as well.

Not sure how I can solve this issue but you can ask me questions and I will be happy to answer them.

Thanks...

Comment: Is there separate power for the external HDD, or is it using power via the USB port? In that case maybe the voltage gets too low for the keyboard. If that is not the problem, it is possible that the external HDD or the adapter/box for it will disturb the keyboard. Sometimes it is a workaround to connect some of the USB devices via a USB hub.

Comment: It is using power via the USB port. I tried the USB hub option but it did not work. It is surely the power distribution of USB ports but I am not sure if it is restricted by the OS or simply low voltage...

Comment: Is your USB hub supplied by a separate power cable? In that case, how did it not work? Was it the same or different symptoms (compared to your original configuration without a USB hub)?